# Split a string as column and rows in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

I just want to split a string as column and rows in MS SQL

**Example:**

String  : `26412|7|554.40#42470|10|1504.40#49606|10|274.40#378982|10|425.84`

Delimiter :  `|` as **column**,

Delimiter : `#` as **rows**

help to find solution Thanks in advance.

Expected Output:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
-----------------------
26412    07    554.40
42470    10    1504.40
49606    10    274.40
378982   10    425.84
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server (2016 adds a string split function...)

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far? This is a great place to start: [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be done with the help of XML:

```
DECLARE @str nvarchar(max) = N'26412|7|554.40#42470|10|1504.40#49606|10|274.40#378982|10|425.84',
        @xml xml

SELECT @xml = CAST('<s><b>'+REPLACE(REPLACE(@str,'#','</b></s><s><b>'),'|','</b><b>')+'</b></s>' as xml)


SELECT  t.v.value('b[1]','int') as Col1,
        t.v.value('b[2]','int') as Col2,
        t.v.value('b[3]','float') as Col3
FROM @xml.nodes('/s') as t(v)
```

Output:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
26412   7       554,4
42470   10      1504,4
49606   10      274,4
378982  10      425,84
```

Comment: @gofr1:I like this approach,do you have any links for further examples

Comment: @TheGameiswar I learn it from my coworker, and then find out few answers with that approach on SO. Use this pretty often when I need string splitting. [Here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1771/splitting-delimited-strings-using-xml-in-sql-server/) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Using one of the split strings from [here](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings):

```
declare @str varchar(max)
set @str='26412|7|554.40#42470|10|1504.40#49606|10|274.40#378982|10|425.84'

;with cte(mainitem)
as
(
select * from [dbo].[SplitStrings_Numbers](@str,'#') b 
)
,cte1 as 
(select *,row_number() over (partition by mainitem order by mainitem) as rn from cte c
cross apply
[dbo].[SplitStrings_Numbers](c.mainitem,'|')  )
select 
max(case when rn=1 then cast(item as varchar(100)) end) as col1,
max(case when rn=2 then cast(item as varchar(100))end) as col2,
max(case when rn=3 then cast(item as varchar(100)) end) as col3
from cte1 
group by mainitem
```

**Output:**

```
26412   7   554.40
378982  10  425.84
42470   10  1504.40
49606   10  274.40
```

Comment: @Kannappan:please see the article i referrred

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
DECLARE @List NVARCHAR(max) = '26412|7|554.40#42470|10|1504.40#49606|10|274.40#378982|10|425.84'

SELECT col1 AS ActualData
    ,PARSENAME(REPLACE(col1, '|', '.'), 4) col1
    ,PARSENAME(REPLACE(col1, '|', '.'), 3) col2
    ,substring(col1, (LEN(col1) - CHARINDEX('|', REVERSE(col1))) + 2, len(col1)) AS Col3
FROM (
    SELECT y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)') AS col1
    FROM (
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' + REPLACE(@List, '#', '</i><i>') + '</i>').query('.')
        ) AS a
    CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
    ) T
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working very well  for me in MySql 5.5

```
 CREATE TABLE split ( id INT, str VARCHAR(50) );
 INSERT INTO split VALUES (1, 'Smith'), (2, 'Julio|Jones|Falcons'), (3,
 'White|Snow'), (4, 'Paint|It|Red'), (5, 'Green|Lantern'), (6, 'Brown|bag');


        DELIMITER |

        CREATE PROCEDURE SplitColumnsToRows ()
        BEGIN
          DECLARE id1 INT (100);
          DECLARE str1 VARCHAR (100);
          DECLARE done INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
          DECLARE tokens INT DEFAULT 0;
          DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
          DECLARE token VARCHAR (100);
          DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
          SELECT
            id,
            str
          FROM
            split;
          DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
          OPEN cur;
          parse :
          LOOP
            FETCH cur INTO id1,
            str1;
            IF done = 1
            THEN LEAVE parse;
            END IF;
            SET tokens =
            (SELECT
              LENGTH(str1) - LENGTH(REPLACE(str1, '|', '')) + 1);
            DELETE
            FROM
              split
            WHERE id = id1
              AND str = str1;
            SET i = 1;
            WHILE
              i <= tokens DO IF i = tokens
              THEN SET token = str1;
              ELSE SET token = SUBSTR(str1, 1, INSTR(str1, '|') - 1);
              SET str1 = SUBSTR(str1, INSTR(str1, '|') + 1, LENGTH(str1));
              END IF;
              INSERT INTO split
              VALUES
                (id1, token);
              SET i = i + 1;
            END WHILE;
          END LOOP parse;
          CLOSE cur;
        END |

        DELIMITER;
```